# Why cant I add email to serializeUser in passport js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

While accessing the user object in serializeUser() function, I am only able to access the id, username and password and not any other keys. console.log(user) returns the entire user object including email but user.email returns undefined. How can I access email inside serializeUser?

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.email); //returns undefined
});
```